# Problem with UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I have a problem with a UILabel.

Imagine I have a string `@"I am a software engineer and working on iphone Apps"`.
I want to show this string in 3 lines in UILabel am doing these steps

1. Make a UILabel IBOutlet in a custom cell and name it courseHeadingLabel;
2. In table View I write the code:

`cell.courseHeadingLabel.numberOfLines=0;`

`cell.courseHeadingLabel.text=couseHeading;`

`cell.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;`

However this doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the right thing setting `numberOfLines` to `0`, it will use as many lines as needed (but if 3 lines is a strict maximum, set this to `3` instead).

However, for the wrapping to occur, you need to give your label a correct width and height: if the height is not big enough, you won't see the other lines under the first one.

Change the height by setting the `frame` attribute of `courseHeadingLabel` (setting the `height` to three times the current `height`should do it).

Something like this:

```
CGRect r = cell.courseHeadingLabel.frame;
r.size.height *= 3;
cell.courseHeadingLabel.frame = r;
```

Answer (score 0):

set numberOfLines to 3 and also increase the height to 3 times